# Where does the gradient of a Lipschitz function end up in?

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions, differential-operators

Let $X = \mathsf{Lip(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)}$ be the space of (globally, or perhaps locally) Lipschitz functions, say from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. From [Rademacher's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208841/proof-of-rademacher-s-theorem) we know that $f \in \mathsf{Lip(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)} $ is almost everywhere differentiable.

What's the natural codomain $Y$ for the gradient (or jacobian) map $\nabla$?

$$ \nabla: \mathsf{Lip(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)} \rightarrow Y $$

(for example, if $X=\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$, the "natural codomain" would be $Y=\mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{R})$ due to the fundamental theorem of calculus - and I am not even sure about $X=\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R^n})$)

Comment: How about bounded linear operator?

Comment: @Andrew sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: $f$ $L$ Lipschitz will have Jacobian with spectral norm bounded by $L$

Comment: Ok, but why would you end up with something linear?

Comment: Because the derivative, by definition, is a linear operator

Comment: You are saying that the derivative of $t^3$ is linear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148421/discussion-between-rod-and-andrew).